How to map PUT/POST Request with Symfonys #[MapRequestPayload] Attribute to nested DTO
I am currently playing around with the #[MapRequestPayload] Attribute of Symfony. I used it before for flat DTOs, worked like a charm. Now i am trying to map a nested DTO. My SearchResult DTO has one property $details, which holds a Collection of Details DTOs. Here are the two DTOs:
class SearchResult
{
    /**
     * @var Collection<int, Details>
     */
    private Collection $details;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->details = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getDetails(): Collection
    {
        return $this->details;
    }

    public function setDetails(Collection $details): SearchResult
    {
        $this->details = $details;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addDetails(Details $details): self
    {
        if (!$this->details->contains($details)) {
            $this->details[] = $details;
        }
        return $this;
    }
}


class Details
{
    private string $name;
    private string $ticker;
    private ?string $homepageUrl = null;
    private ?string $description = null;
    private ?string $currency = null;
    private ?int $sicCode = null;
    private ?string $sicDescription = null;

    public function getName(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): Details
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTicker(): ?string
    {
        return $this->ticker;
    }

    public function setTicker(string $ticker): Details
    {
        $this->ticker = $ticker;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHomepageUrl(): ?string
    {
        return $this->homepageUrl;
    }

    public function setHomepageUrl(?string $homepageUrl): Details
    {
        $this->homepageUrl = $homepageUrl;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(?string $description): Details
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCurrency(): ?string
    {
        return $this->currency;
    }

    public function setCurrency(?string $currency): Details
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSicCode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sicCode;
    }

    public function setSicCode(?int $sicCode): Details
    {
        $this->sicCode = $sicCode;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSicDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->sicDescription;
    }

    public function setSicDescription(?string $sicDescription): Details
    {
        $this->sicDescription = $sicDescription;
        return $this;
    }
}


This is the controller action:
#[Route('/handle', name: 'handle', methods: ['POST'])]
    public function handle(#[MapRequestPayload] SearchResult $searchResult): JsonResponse
    {
        // Do something here 
        return new JsonResponse();
    }

And finally the payload which hit the above action:
{
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "Apple Inc",
            "ticker": "AAPL",
            "homepage_url": null,
            "description": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sic_code": null,
            "sic_description": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Tesla Inc",
            "ticker": "TSLA",
            "homepage_url": null,
            "description": null,
            "currency": null,
            "sic_code": null,
            "sic_description": null
        }
    ]
}

As a response i can see a 422 Error in my symfony profiler. The corresponding ValidationFailedException reads as follows: "details: This value should be of type unknown." Am i missing something very obvious here? I think the DTOs replicate the request correctly and should therefor be populated with the data. Also the NULL values in the payload should be fine, since the setters accept NULL as well.
Thank you in advance!

Try to use array instead Collection and annotate $details using @var Details[] instead of Collection. Serializer may not understand generic types.
